# MYSQL Requiring one among distinct values in query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that holds transactions from various accounts.  Most accounts are assigned a single sales person, but on occasion an account may be sold something from a salesperson not specifically assigned to the account  (Sales_Person_Name).  Each month I identify these by counting the number of distinct salespeople by account, if greater than one the account is returned in the query:

```
SELECT 
account_nbr,
cust_name,
COUNT( Distinct Sales_Rep_Name)multiplereps
FROM transactions
WHERE month=3 and year=2016 
GROUP BY account_nbr
HAVING multiplereps >1
```

I now what to refine the query where one of the distinct names is a given, say "John Smith".
There are 80 possible salespeople.  What could I add to the query to make certain that it only returns accounts where one of the multiple sale reps is "John Smith"?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: SELECT 
account_nbr,
cust_name,
COUNT( Distinct Sales_Rep_Name)multiplereps
FROM transactions t1
WHERE month=3 and year=2016 
GROUP BY account_nbr HAVING multiplereps >1 and EXISTS (select * from transaction t2 where t2.account_nbr =t1.account_nbr and t2.sales_Person_Name="John Smith")

Comment: Seriously, 10 minutes after post? Thanks so much.

Comment: @sab If that's a solution, would be better as an answer that can be accepted.